# Why was my question closed even if it was genuine question?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question *[Django automatically inheriting “abstract = true” from an abstract meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518655/django-automatically-inheriting-abstract-true-from-abstract-meta-calss)*.

Now I was facing that problem and someone perfectly answered it as well.
Why was closed? That question can save someone else time if she was stuck on the same problem like me.

If the wording was not OK, someone could have changed it, but they closed it.

Comment: People like to see question in front of their eyes.. up until 22 minutes ago, there was no direct question in your question.

Comment: Some of us voted to close when there wasn't a question. Six edits later there might be...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reopened your post, but you might want to edit it to explicitly ask a question.

Comment: I don't think there was anything for downvote in that questions. It was tricky question